# How do I write an awk script that catch ping's time in seconds?

Tags: scripts, ping, awk

How can I make `ping` show ms and time in (seconds)?

I found this script:

```
$ ping google.com | awk 'BEGIN {FS="[=]|[ ]"} {print $11}'
16.8
16.8
15.7
18.8
```

How do I write an awk script which brings out in seconds?

```
1  16.8
2  16.8
3  15.7
4  18.8
```

The stored values need to save to file >> file.txt

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and run this command:

```
ping -c 4 google.com | awk -F "[=]|[ ]" '/bytes from/{print NR "\t" $11/1000 }' > out.txt
```

Where:

- `-c 4` (eg. 4)

  Limits the number of requests, so that "awk" can write into a file.
- `$11/1000`

  Converts milliseconds to seconds

Comment: Ah... `NR` would do instead of `count`.

Comment: @muru, I wanted to be fast. :\

Comment: Now it should work.

Comment: why not start from 2

Comment: @Jozef397, I don't understand.

Comment: @Jozef397 Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me a upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). ;)

Comment: @Jozef397 What do you mean with `why not start from 2`

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on `awk`, you could do:

```
$ ping -c 4 google.com | 
    awk -F "[= ]" '$2=="bytes"{print ++c "\t" $(NF-1)/1000 }' 
1   0.0361
2   0.036
3   0.0357
4   0.0363
```

Personally, I would do it using `grep` and only use `awk` for multiplying the milliseconds by 1000:

```
$ ping -c4 google.com | grep -Po 'time=\K[\d.]+' | awk '{print NR,$1/1000}'
1 0.0357
2 0.0364
3 0.0364
4 0.0364
```

Or Perl:

```
$ ping -c4 google.com | perl -lne '/time=([\d.]+)/ && print ++$c,"\t",$1/1000'
1   0.0361
2   0.0357
3   0.0363
4   0.0361
```

To save the output in a file, just use redirection. Add `> outfile` to any of the commands above:

```
ping -c4 google.com | perl -lne '/time=([\d.]+)/ && print ++$c,"\t",$1/1000' > outfile
```